# How to use RegEx in C# to take all the matching strings into a collection

Tags: c#, regex, string, c#-4.0, collections

I want to take all the matches into a collection, or at least a new string with my values separated by blank spaces.

```
var srcString = @"foo foo %%match1%%, foo %%match2%%, %%match3%% foo foo";

var output = Regex.Match(srcString, @"\%\%(.*)\%\%").Groups[1].Value;
```

where output, must be a collection with "match1" as an element, "match2" as next one, and so on, or at least something like "match1 match2 match3".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var srcString = @"foo foo %%match1%%, foo %%match2%%, %%match3%% foo foo";

IEnumberable<string> results = Regex.Matches(srcString, @"\%\%(.*?)\%\%").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var srcString = @"foo foo %%match1%%, foo %%match2%%, %%match3%% foo foo";
            var match = Regex.Match(srcString, @"%%([^%]+)%%");
            while (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
```

Output:

```
match1
match2
match3
```